# Google Calendar API : java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class

Tags: java, google-app-engine, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to integrate Google Calendar in my application. after authenticating the user I am trying to read all the available calendars list for the authenticated user. Calling the method to get the calendars list throws java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class.

Here's what I tried.

```
Calendar.Builder builder = new Calendar.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), null);
builder.setCalendarRequestInitializer(new CalendarRequestInitializer(accessToken));
builder.setApplicationName("myApp");

Calendar calendarService = builder.build();

CalendarList calendarList = calendarService.calendarList().list().execute();
```

I have included the google client library jars and calendar api services jar
"google-api-services-calendar-v3-rev60-1.17.0-rc.jar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys I found the issue. It's all about the jars what are included. I just cleaned up all the duplicated jar, various versions, and removed all the google-api-client beta jars. It worked.